# C# Selenium - implicit and explicit waits not working on web elements during page load

Tags: c#, selenium

C# Selenium - implicit and explicit waits not working on web elements during page load.

Are the Selenium implicit and explicit waits supposed to work on web elements during the page load. Is there a different way to handle this?

I am doing as shown below:

```
 IWebElement flightsTable = new WebDriverWait(this.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120))
            .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath(DisplayFlightsXpath)));

        if (!flightsTable.Displayed)
        {
            throw new NoSuchWindowException("Flights are not loaded on the overview page1.");
        }
```

Comment: What make you think they are not working?

Comment: In the above code sample, the wait is not working and throwing the NoSuchWindowException exception. It works at all other places, not sure whats different here.

Comment: If the element exists it doesn't mean it displayed. Use `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` for this.

Comment: I am new to Selenium stack, could you please specify how to do it?

Comment: You used `ExpectedConditions.ElementExists`. Use `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` instead.

Comment: More expected conditions [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm)

Comment: My bad, did not see it, got it. Thanks!

Comment: I have implicit wait (this.WebDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(Configuration.DefaultWaitTime);) set on the driver and it is recommended not to combine implicit and explicit wait types in Selenium. Is there a way to make this work with the implicit wait time.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with combining implicit and explicit wait. On the contrary.

Comment: Ok, do I need to reset the implicit wait time when using explicit wait on this one? and set the implicit wait again after checking for this?. Is there a way to make it work with the implicit wait setup?

Comment: No, there is no connection between the two.